# Android Firebase retrieve value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a value from the Firebase.

I am using this piece of code to get that, but all the methods I call on score1 return null.

```
private void onSignedInInitialize(String username) {
    mUsername = username;
    final DatabaseReference reference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    Query query = reference.child("scores").orderByChild("username").equalTo(mUsername);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            Score scores1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Score.class);
            Log.d(TAG, " scores1  " + scores1 + " datasnapshot to String " + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            Log.d(TAG, " user " + scores1.getUsername());
            Log.d(TAG, " user " + scores1.getUsername());
            scoresTextView.setText(scores1.getScore());
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

My Firebase structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/377AA.png)

I used the example in their documentation (with Post class) and also searched on Google but i can't find how I can get the value of scores.
Thank you for your answer.

This is Score class

```
public class Score {

    private String username;
    private String score;

    public Score() {

    }

    public Score(String username, String score) {
        this.username = username;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

Comment: Make the variables public then try again

Comment: It's the same, still null

Comment: No one knows how to obtain that value?

Comment: Try this  'mMessagesDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("scores");' in childevent listener ' mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Questions questions = dataSnapshot.getValue(Questions.class);

                 
                }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your database image shows, the database nodes that are instances of `Score` are *children* of location `scores`.  Update your code as shown below.

A second problem is that the `score` in the database is an integer, not a String as your `Score` class expects.  You must either update the DB to contain strings or change `Score` to handle `score` as an integer.  Also, your `Score` class is missing a setter method for `username`.

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Score scores1 = snap.getValue(Score.class);
                Log.d(TAG, " scores1  " + scores1 + " datasnapshot to String " + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, " user= " + scores1.getUsername());
                Log.d(TAG, " score= " + scores1.getScore());
                scoresTextView.setText(scores1.getScore());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: NO DATA");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: Forgot to see database, you are right. And I think setter method is not required if you don't want to push data